# How to initialize once and pass that same value to another function again and again?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following function . This will be called everytime the browser is resized and every time I want to pass the same initial value of the `this.original_ul` to this function `doLayout()` . It is computed only once inside an initialization function separately . Right now what is happening is second time when it is called , the changes to the `$ul` variable  also is getting reflected on  `this.original_ul` . How can I possibly prevent this ?

```
doLayout : function () {
    alert('doLayout');
    var size, $ul, $lis, loop, i;
    size = this.computeElesPerCol();
    $ul = this.original_ul; // I wanna  preserve this between calls
    $lis = $ul.children().filter(':gt(' + (size - 1) + ')');
    loop = Math.ceil($lis.length / size);
    i = 0;

    $ul.css('float', 'left').wrap("<div style='overflow: hidden'></div>");

    for (; i < loop; i = i + 1) {
      $ul = $("<ul />").css('float', 'left').append($lis.slice(i * size, (i * size) + 4)).insertAfter($ul);
      $ul.css("list-style","none");
    }
  }
```

**Edit:** : `this` is a reference to the javascript object WebFloatLayout which basically does a multi column layout depending on the available height every time the browser is resized . The initial input is a long list of `<lis>` in a single `<ul>` . Here is how it gets initialized :

```
     initialize:function () {
    var webFloatLayout = this;
    //call super parent initialize which will set the main dom element of component
    ec.comp.Component.prototype.initialize.call(this);
    var innerDivId = this.id + "_inner";
    innerDivId = innerDivId.replace(new RegExp(ec.config.separator, "g"), "\\" + ec.config.separator);
    $(document).ready(function() {
      webFloatLayout.original_ul = $("#" + innerDivId).find(">:first-child");
      webFloatLayout.original_ul.css("list-style","none");
      webFloatLayout.layout();
    });
  },
```

Comment: Nothing changes the "original_ul" property in that code. How is it set?  What is it?

Comment: Also calling that code on the "resize" event will result in really terrible performance. Browsers fire "resize" very frequently while the user drags window handles, and doing DOM manipulations on each event will be really slow.

Comment: @Pointy we handle that through  setTimeout to avoid firing all the time

Comment: Ah OK then :-)  Well it might help to know what `this` is in that function.

Comment: @Pointy edited the question to give more information.

Comment: OK well then the answer below that suggests cloning the original DOM structure is probably the right idea, at least basically.

Comment: @Pointy this is applying every change to clone and the changes are not getting updated to the original .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14521/discussion-between-geek-and-pointy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method:

```
$ul = this.original_ul.clone();
```

Comment: this is applying every change to clone and the changes are not getting updated to the original

Comment: @Geek: "...the changes to the $ul variable also is getting reflected on this.original_ul . How can I possibly prevent this ?" - isn't that exactly what you asked for?